# Multiple Videos Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, video, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm using vb.net and was able to One play video on DISPLAY 1 or 2 or 3. But I want to play 2 videos at the same time. And I want one to play on display 2 and the other at display 3. They don't have to start at the same time. But the goal is to play a video on DISPLAY 3 while there's already one playing on DISPLAY 2. I made a windows media Player on form 2, and another wmp on form 3. If I Play a video on form 2 to be displayed on display 2, there's no problem. But when I called another task to play another video on form 3 to be displayed on display 3, It opens form3 but doesn't play the video on windows media player that's in that form. Why?

Comment: Creating to objects might do that trick?

Comment: @VisualVincent why not 2* hahahah

Comment: @Werdna : Whatever you like. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent II it is then :)

Comment: Solved it. However. If I try to play it both in full screen, it doesn't. For example. I form1.show() on \\.\DISPLAY2, with a wmp on it that plays automatically on full screen. However if I form2.show on \\.\DISPLAY3 with a wmp2 on it, it plays the video in it but It cannot be in fullscreen. Why?

Comment: Because two fullscreen apps/windows can't be run at the same time? They don't work the same way as normal Windows Forms, you know.

Comment: Create two forms instead and dock-fill one media player in each, then make the form maximized and borderless. Now you'll be able to place them on two different screens (the media player should **not** be set to run in fullscreen).